# How to collect JSON in c# posted from angularjs?

Tags: c#, json, angularjs

I'm a basic developer, I just need to collect the following JSON data in a c# file:

```
{
  "text":"This is a message !!!",
  "userid":"some_id",
  "username":"username",
  "fname":"some_name",
  "lname":"some_surname",
  "iurl":"url_here",
  "type":"some_type"
}
```

The above array is posted using angularjs.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('WorkingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.post = [];
    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        $scope.post.text = $scope.form.text;

        if ($scope.post.text != '') {
            $scope.post.unshift($scope.post.text);           
            $scope.post.text = '';
        }

        $scope.remItem = function ($index) {
            $scope.post.splice($index , -1);
        }

        $scope.form.userid = "some_id";
        $scope.form.username = "username";
        $scope.form.fname = "some_name";
        $scope.form.lname = "some_surname";
        $scope.form.iurl = "url_here";
        $scope.form.type = "some_type";
        $scope.showValues = JSON.stringify($scope.form);
    }
}]);
```

As clearly seen above `showValues` returns the array.

Now I just wanted to collect data in my ValuesController.cs file. Can anyone suggest how to do that ?

Comment: What technology are you using? ServiceStack, Web Api, ASP.NET MVC, WCF?

Comment: @alexw MVC  with Web Api

Comment: `$scope.showValues = JSON.stringify($scope.form)`. Isn't showValues a string? See the value in debugger. You can use `JavaScriptSerializer` in C# method to deserialize JSON string to an object.

Comment: @aSharma got your point.. but some refference code is neccessary to post from angularjs to c# , what would be that ? some tutorial link would help . :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this code:
***Create a service.***

```
 app.service("angularService", function ($http) {
     this.AddValues= function (showValues) {
            var response = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "api/values/YourmethodName",
                data: showValues
            });
            return response;
        }
    });
```

In your controller: Inject your Service here in this way to implement its method/service

```
app.controller('WorkingCtrl', ['$scope','angularService',function ($scope, angularService) {

$scope.submitForm = function () {
$scope.form = {};

 $scope.form.userid = "some_id";
    $scope.form.username = "username";
    $scope.form.fname = "some_name";
    $scope.form.lname = "some_surname";
    $scope.form.iurl = "url_here";
    $scope.form.type = "some_type";
    $scope.showValues = JSON.stringify($scope.form);

   angularService.AddValues(showValues ).then(function (result) {
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service which sends the data to your controller. You need something along these lines:

```
app.factory('WorkingService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
     saveData: function (showValues ) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post(yourMVCUrl, showValues ).then(function (result) {
             deferred.resolve(result);               
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

In your angular controller, just call the service `WorkingService.saveData($scope.form)`.

Comment: No need for a `deferred` here. See: [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You can make call to your MVC controller (ValuesController.cs) using this code in your Angular controller:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Values/TestMethod',
    data: $scope.showValues,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
 }).
success(function (data) {
    //do some operations with the return data if the MVC controller returns data
}).
error(function () {
   alert("Error has happened..");
});
```

It is better to put the ajax request in a factory service and from your controller to call the http method from the service